# Stackoverflow error with @GET restful annotation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, payara

So I have tried returning multiple types of variables, including User, List and Response. All of these give me back a stackoverflow error in the get path page. I have found through the server log it is a serializing recursion, however I cannot seem to fix it, no matter how I try it. Have seen multiple online tutorials/pages on stackoverflow and still I can fix it.

I am running payara version 184 and java 8 ee, and these are project specifications, so I cant change the tecnologies. Intellij Idea Ultimate IDE and chrome browser/postman to check url.

```
public class User {
private String nome;
private int idade;
private String empresa;
private String email;
//private Boolean auth;

public User (String n , int i, String e, String em/*, Boolean a*/){
    this.nome = n;
    this.idade = i;
    this. empresa = e;
    this.email = em;
    //this.auth = a;
}

public User getUser(){
    return this;
}
```

interface for the restful class methods
    `@GET
    @Path(ApplicationPaths.GET)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @APIResponse(responseCode = "200")
    User getJson(
            @Parameter(ref = Parameters.QUERY)
            @QueryParam(Parameters.QUERY)
                    String query);`

Actual class implementation

```
@ApplicationScoped 
public class KickoffApiImpl implements KickoffApi {

@Inject
private KickoffService kickoffService;

@Override
public User getJson(final String query) {
    /*
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User("pedro", 22, "ctw", "pelan05@gmail.com"));
    users.add(new User("paulo", 50, "ctw", "123abc@gmail.com"));
    users.add(new User("maria", 32, "ctw", "abc123@gmail.com"));

    return users.get(1);
    */

    User u = new User("maria", 32, "ctw", "abc123@gmail.com");
    return u;
    //return Response.ok(kickoffService.getUser()).build();
}
```

My expected output would be a Json page with the 'User' class info on the browser.

P.S.: Server Log error:
https://pastebin.com/xgRfazE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, funny enough I solved my own question by looking at my post. So the recursion was due to the getUser method I implemented in the User class. TY if you tried to read and solve this.